# Given two directory names, how can I get relative name of one as if another is working dir in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In my Rails application, I need to create a symlink between two files inside `RAILS_ROOT`.  The names of target and symlink are given as absolute paths.  However, I want to create a symlink that uses relative paths, so the application folder could easily be moved.

In other words, from `RAILS_ROOT/path/foo/bar` and `RAILS_ROOT/path/baz` I want to get `../../baz` as an answer.

Is there a library function (or a simple one-liner) to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`relative_path_from`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Pathname.html#M001722) method of a Pathname.